# Is it possible to be better than O(N+M) for Codility lesson MaxCounters using python?

Tags: python

This is the code I am using for the Codility lesson: [MaxCounters](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/max_counters/)

```
def solution(N, A):
    counters = [0] * N
    max_c = 0
    for el in A:
        if el >= 1 and el <= N:
            counters[el-1] += 1
            max_c = max(counters[el-1], max_c)
        elif el > N:
            counters = [max_c] * N
    return counters
```

Every test passes but the last one ("all max_counter operations") times out after 7 seconds so the result is just 88% with time complexity of O(N+M).

Is it possible to improve the time complexity of the algorithm and get 100% test result using Python?

#### The MaxCounters task

You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:

- increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
- max counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.

A non-empty array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:

- if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
- if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max counter.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

- N and M are integers within the range [1..100,000];
- each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].

Comment: Please make sure your question is self-contained. We don't know what MaxCounters lesson from Codility is, and the question has to continue to make sense even if Codility went out of business. Supplementary links are fine, but everything needed to answer the question should be inside the question if at all possible.

Comment: Have you tried not calculating the maximum value each time you increment a counter and just calculate the overall maximum whenever you need it?

Comment: Some ideas: First, at `elif el > N`, you should actually compare `elif el == N+1` as specified by the problem. Second, idk if `[max_c]*N` allocates a new array or not, that'd be worth checking: if it does, you should instead write your own `for` loop to change the elements of the existing array instead of allocating a new one. Finally, a remark on the O-notation: It's important to keep it as low as possible, but the constant hidden in it can be just as important in reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** following up on the discussion in the comments to this answer, tracking the last operation to avoid unnecessarily resetting the array in successive max_counter operations was the key to achieving the goal. Here's what the different solutions (one keeping track of the max and the second calculating the max on demand) would look like implementing that change:

```
def solution(N, A):
    counters = [0] * N
    max_c = 0
    last_was_max = False
    for el in A:
        if el <= N:
            counters[el - 1] += 1
            max_c = max(counters[el - 1], max_c)
            last_was_max = False
        elif not last_was_max:
            counters = [max_c] * N
            last_was_max = True
    return counters


def solution2_1(N, A):
    counters = [0] * N
    last_was_max = False
    for el in A:
        if el <= N:
            counters[el - 1] += 1
            last_was_max = False
        elif not last_was_max:
            counters = [max(counters)] * N
            last_was_max = True
    return counters
```

I am not aware which implementation was used in the submission.

---

First, you're wasting some time in your if conditions: there's no need to check for the integer being greater or equal to 1, that's a given from the exercise. Then, there's no need to evaluate a second elif-statement, simply go for an else there. If the first condition is not met, the second will be met by definition of the exercise

Second, according to my testing, just calculating the maximum at the time it is needed is much faster than keeping track of it through all the runs. This is likely due to the fact that the max-operation will only occur very rarely, especially for large values of M and therefore you're wasting time keeping track of stuff many times vs only calculating the maximum a few times during the run.

Addressing @Nearoo's comment, it appears reassigning the array does in fact change the physical address, but according to some tests I ran reassigning is much faster than the for loop anyway.

```
def solution2(N, A):
    counters = [0] * N
    for el in A:
        if el <= N:
            counters[el - 1] += 1
        else:
            counters = [max(counters)] * N
    return counters
```

This solution I came up with outperformed your solution by a solid factor of 2-3 on several test runs with different seed values. Here's the code to reproduce:

```
import random

random.seed(101)
N = random.randint(1, 100000)
M = random.randint(1, 100000)
A = [random.randint(1, N + 1) for i in range(M)]

%timeit solution(N,A)
>>> 11.7 ms ± 805 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit solution2(N,A)
>>> 3.63 ms ± 169 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out how to optimize the if conditions. This can be done because of the assumptions from the exercise. Your solution actually has time complexity of O(N*M) even if it performs better for your test case as the maximum is calculated very rarely.

Comment: The expected valeue for N is 50000, which means that on average, a maximum operation will be performed only once for every 50001 elements in A. I am pretty sure you can throw theoretical calculations out of the window for this use case, because the chance for a max operation is inversely proportional to the cost of said operation - the higher the amount of counters, the more expensive the max operation, but at the same time, the lower the chance of one actually occurring.

Comment: In fact, the chance of a max operation occurring is 1/(N+1) and the complexity is N. Assuming the counter increment can be done in constant time, the complexity of my algorithm should amount to M*[N/(N+1) * 1 + 1/(N+1) * N] = M*[(N+1)/(N+1)]=M, where N/(N+1) is the chance of an increment occurring times the constant time cost 1 and 1/(N+1) is the chance of a max occurring multiplied by the cost N

Comment: in praxis you are right and I would also prefer the `max(counters)` solution. It also is much more readable. This was actually the solution I submitted first to Codility but it fails on the last three tests with a timeout which results in a score of just 40%

Comment: I put some more thought into cases with a high count of max operations - you might be able to cheat out some improvement by eliminating successive max operations as they don't change the output and thus allow for the step to be skipped. This could be achieved by keeping track if the last op was a max with a boolean variable and only resetting the array if needed

Comment: Great! I'll edit my answer and solution accordingly for future reference

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 100% solution:

```
# MaxCounters
def solution(N, A):
    count = [0] * N
    max_count = 0
    last_max = False
    for val in A:
        if val == N + 1 and last_max == False:
            count = [max_count] * N
            last_max = True
            continue
        if val <= N:
            count[val - 1] += 1
            max_count = max(count[val - 1], max_count)
            last_max = False
    return count
```

Comment: The slightest inversion of those if statements drops the result to 66%!! I'm astonished.

Using a while in place of a for loop I achieved 88% as the last test case hit max time out.

Comment: What's the point of tracking `last_max`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    # MaxCounters
def solution(N, A):
    max_counter = 0
    list_counters = [0]*N
    if N < min(A):
        return list_counters
    for i in A:
        if i <= N:
            list_counters[i-1] += 1
            max_counter = max(list_counters[i-1], max_counter)
        else:
            list_counters = [max_counter]*N
    return list_counters
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Python.
But my kotlin solution even run faster when more MaxCounter at the extreme test.
[Check the Report](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training368KEQ-CZ3/)

▶extreme_large

all max_counter operations✔OK

1. 0.280s OK
2. 0.264s OK

I believe this test is about avoid the full update on the array during max process.
If you can avoid that you should able to get the 100%.
So try your best to stop a full array update no matter on which language.

I get a 88% at my first try, and I used an hour to getting this original new answer. After a max operation all counter has same value, so its meaning less to keep check each counter until the final max operation. I create the array AFTER I found the last Max Operation, so there has no array full update require at all

Answer (score 0):

actually, this gives a 100% score:

```
def solution(N, A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    maxcount=0
    counter=[maxcount]*N
    can_be_updated = True
    for J in A:
        if(J<=N ):
            counter[J-1]+=1
            maxcount = max(maxcount,counter[J-1])
            can_be_updated = True
        else:
            if(can_be_updated):
                counter = [maxcount]*N
                can_be_updated = False
    return(counter)   
pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, every solution that involves creating new list every time there is an update will fail on "large_random2" test. You have to cache two max values. One for global max (minimum for every value) and current max (current maximum value in whole array).

```
def solution(N, A):
global_max = 0
current_max = 0
result = [0] * N
canUpdate = True
for i in A:
    if i <= N:
        if result[i-1] <= global_max:
            result[i-1] = global_max + 1
        else:
            result[i-1] += 1
        current_max = max(current_max, result[i-1])
        canUpdate = True
    elif canUpdate:
        canUpdate = False
        global_max = current_max
    # print(result)
for i, val in enumerate(result):
    if val < global_max:
        result[i] = global_max
return result
```

Comment: Can you explain the code a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This solution gives 77% performance but timeouts at `large_random2`
It uses a `max_counter` to track the max counter value which can be used to update the counters all at once.

```
def solution(N,A):
    counters = [0] * N
    max_counter = 0
    for x in A:
        if x >= 1 and x <= N:
            counters[x-1] = counters[x-1]+1
            if counters[x-1] > max_counter:
                max_counter = counters[x-1]
        elif x == N+1:
            counters = [max_counter] * N
    
    return counters
```